# JS CodeCoverage analysis with Sonar

Tags: javascript, maven, jenkins, code-coverage, sonarqube

I have a JavaScript project, which I am analysing with Sonar. Everything works fine, except the code coverage analysis.

I am using Karma to create the line coverage `lcov.info` file.

When I do the analysis from my cmd / cywin, with:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Pci-sonar-js
```

Everything works fine and Sonar displays the code coverage, when I do the same from my Jenkins Job. The Code Coverage is displayed with 0%!

Sonar parses the lcov.info file, and there is no differences in the output of the analysis, except for the parsing duration of the file (cmd~60ms, jenkins~30ms).

**Sonar part of pom.xml**

```
<profile>
    <id>ci-sonar-js</id>

    <properties>
        <sonar.branch>JavaScript</sonar.branch>
        <sonar.language>js</sonar.language>
        <sonar.exclusions>src/test/webapp/lib/**,**/datepick.min.js,**/fileupload.js,**/fileupload.min.js,**/moment.js,**/moment.min.js,**/script.min.js,**/syntaxhighlighter.js,**/syntaxhighlighter.min.js</sonar.exclusions>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sonar.sourceEncoding>

        <sonar.javascript.jstest.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports/</sonar.javascript.jstest.reportsPath>
        <sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath>target/lcov.info</sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath>

        <ci.build.sourceDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/META-INF/public/js/min/</ci.build.sourceDirectory>
        <ci.build.testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/webapp/</ci.build.testSourceDirectory>
    </properties>

    <build>
        ...
    </build>
</profile>
```

**Jenkins Log:**

```
[Sonar JavaScript] $ C:\tools\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin\mvn.bat -f "c:\workspace\Sonar JavaScript\pom.xml" -e -B sonar:sonar -Pci-sonar-js -Dsonar.jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@<my_shortened_db_connection> ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://<my_shortened_hostname>:9000 -Dsonar.branch=JavaScript -Dsonar.language=js
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myProject 1.0.0.05-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.1:sonar (default-cli) @ myProject ---
[INFO] SonarQube version: 3.6.2
[INFO] [16:51:59.960] Load batch settings
[INFO] [16:52:00.007] User cache: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\<my_shortened_user>\.sonar\cache
[INFO] [16:52:00.069] Install plugins
[INFO] [16:52:00.726] Install JDBC driver
[INFO] [16:52:00.741] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:oracle:thin:@<my_shortened_db_connection>
[INFO] [16:52:02.163] Initializing Hibernate
[INFO] [16:52:08.898] Load project settings
[INFO] [16:52:08.913] Apply project exclusions
[INFO] [16:52:09.023] -------------  Scan myProject JavaScript
[INFO] [16:52:09.023] Load module settings
[INFO] [16:52:09.288] Quality profile : [name=Sonar way,language=js]
[INFO] [16:52:09.304] Excluded sources: 
[INFO] [16:52:09.304]   src/test/webapp/lib/**
[INFO] [16:52:09.304]   **/datepick.min.js
[INFO] [16:52:09.304]   **/fileupload.js
[INFO] [16:52:09.304]   **/fileupload.min.js
[INFO] [16:52:09.304]   **/moment.js
[INFO] [16:52:09.304]   **/moment.min.js
[INFO] [16:52:09.304]   **/script.min.js
[INFO] [16:52:09.304]   **/syntaxhighlighter.js
[INFO] [16:52:09.304]   **/syntaxhighlighter.min.js
[INFO] [16:52:09.304] Excluded tests: 
[INFO] [16:52:09.304]   **/package-info.java
[INFO] [16:52:09.335] Configure Maven plugins
[INFO] [16:52:09.367] Compare to previous analysis (2013-09-23)
[INFO] [16:52:09.382] Compare over 5 days (2013-09-18, analysis of 2013-09-23 14:22:37.579)
[INFO] [16:52:09.382] Compare over 30 days (2013-08-24, analysis of 2013-09-23 14:22:37.579)
[INFO] [16:52:09.679] Base dir: c:\workspace\Sonar JavaScript
[INFO] [16:52:09.679] Working dir: c:\workspace\Sonar JavaScript\target\sonar
[INFO] [16:52:09.679] Source dirs: c:\workspace\Sonar JavaScript\target\classes\META-INF\public\js\min
[INFO] [16:52:09.679] Test dirs: c:\workspace\Sonar JavaScript\src\test\webapp
[INFO] [16:52:09.679] Binary dirs: c:\workspace\Sonar JavaScript\target\classes
[INFO] [16:52:09.679] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: de_DE
[INFO] [16:52:09.710] Sensor JavaScriptSourceImporter...
[INFO] [16:52:09.804] Sensor JavaScriptSourceImporter done: 94 ms
[INFO] [16:52:09.804] Sensor JavaScriptSquidSensor...
[INFO] [16:52:11.101] Sensor JavaScriptSquidSensor done: 1297 ms
[INFO] [16:52:11.101] Sensor LCOVSensor...
[INFO] [16:52:11.101] Analysing C:\workspace\Sonar JavaScript\target\lcov.info
[INFO] [16:52:11.132] Sensor LCOVSensor done: 31 ms
[INFO] [16:52:11.132] Sensor JsTestSensor...
[INFO] [16:52:14.382] Sensor JsTestSensor done: 3250 ms
[INFO] [16:52:14.382] Sensor CpdSensor...
[INFO] [16:52:14.382] SonarBridgeEngine is used
[INFO] [16:52:14.382] Cross-project analysis disabled
[INFO] [16:52:14.601] Sensor CpdSensor done: 219 ms
[INFO] [16:52:14.601] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
[INFO] [16:52:14.601] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO] [16:52:14.601] Sensor ProfileSensor...
[INFO] [16:52:14.617] Sensor ProfileSensor done: 16 ms
[INFO] [16:52:14.617] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
[INFO] [16:52:14.632] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 15 ms
[INFO] [16:52:14.632] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
[INFO] [16:52:14.648] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 16 ms
[INFO] [16:52:14.648] Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
[INFO] [16:52:14.664] Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 16 ms
[INFO] [16:52:14.664] Sensor Maven dependencies...
[INFO] [16:52:15.570] Sensor Maven dependencies done: 906 ms
[INFO] [16:52:15.882] Execute decorators...
[INFO] [16:52:19.476] Store results in database
[INFO] [16:52:19.570] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://<my_shortened_hostname>:9000/dashboard/index/com.mycompany:myProject:JavaScript
[INFO] [16:52:19.570] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.doxygen.DoxygenPostJob
[ERROR] [16:52:19.570] The global property 'sonar.doxygen.deploymentPath' is not set. Set it in SONAR and run another analysis.
[INFO] [16:52:19.570] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
[INFO] [16:52:19.570] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
[INFO] [16:52:19.648] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
[INFO] [16:52:19.664] -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2013-08-26 and 2013-09-22
[INFO] [16:52:19.664] -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2012-09-24 and 2013-08-26
[INFO] [16:52:19.664] -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2008-09-29 and 2012-09-24
[INFO] [16:52:19.664] -> Delete data prior to: 2008-09-29
[INFO] [16:52:19.664] -> Clean myProject JavaScript [id=14180]
[INFO] [16:52:19.679] <- Clean snapshot 118948
[INFO] [16:52:19.976] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.AlertBreaker
[INFO] [16:52:19.976] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.ForbiddenConfigurationBreaker
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22.251s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Sep 23 16:52:20 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/172M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sonar analysis completed: SUCCESS
Zeichne Testergebnisse auf.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: I'm not sure to correctly understand: you get the expected code coverage when you run the analysis from the command line, but not when it is executed on Jenkins?

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam yeah, thats crazy right? I already checked, that all nessesary tools are installed on the jenkins server, by executing the build from cmd on the server. Everything works fine. But from within Jenkins it does not. The strangest thing for me is, that the jenkins job finds the lcov.info file and parses it. At the beginning I thought, there might be encoding problems etc. But everything is the same, but some line differences in the lcov.info

Comment: Do you rely on some environment variable for this analysis ? Because when executing something from cmd on the server it does not load such variables

Comment: Also experiencing this, really struggling to isolate any differences between running Sonar locally and from our maven/jenkins environment.